# javascript error on ext.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ext.net

I am new on ext.net framework and I require lots of help.
To begin with the problem I managed to solve the problem regarding the `web.config` file.
Now  I can use the ext.net with ease and no references problem has arrived but now I am having trouble running the code.

As I debug and run the desired solution the error pops up regarding the java script. The error says `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Ext' is undefined`.

I have no idea about the error and it will be helpful if any of you guys would help me on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `Global.asax` file, and within the `RegisterRoutes` Method, ensure you have the following line(s):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{exclude}/{extnet}/ext.axd");
```

The "ext.axd" `IgnoreRoute` is the important one.

The `.RegisterRoutes` method may be located within /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

Hope this helps.